# How can I use guava FluentIterable to simplify Maps transformations?

Tags: java, guava, generic-programming

I often use `Map<U,V>` that I transform and filter to get another `Map<U,V'>`, but the transformation is horribly verbose, I saw `FluentIterable` class in the quesion [Guava: how to combine filter and transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277734/guava-how-to-combine-filter-and-transform), is is possible to use it to simplify the following ?

```
public class GuavaTest {

    public static class A{
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        public A(int a, int b, int c){
            this.a=a; this.b=b; this.c=c;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Example 2
        final Map<String, A> map =Maps.newHashMap();

        map.put("obj1",new A(1,1,1)); map.put("obj2",new A(1,2,1));
        map.put("obj3",new A(1,3,1)); map.put("obj4",new A(1,4,1));

        Function<A, Integer> function = new Function<A, Integer>() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Integer apply(@Nullable A input) {
                return input.b;
            }
        };

        Predicate<Integer> isPair = new Predicate<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(@Nullable Integer input) {
                return input % 2 == 0;
            }
        };

        //Can I use FluentIterable here ??
        Map<String, Integer> stringIntegerMap = Maps.transformValues(map, function);
        Map<String, Integer> stringIntegerMap1 = Maps.filterValues(stringIntegerMap, isPair);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

`FluentIterable` doesn't really do much of anything with maps, and certainly won't shorten your `Function` and `Predicate` implementations.  The only thing that will shorten those is Java 8 lambdas, really.

Comment: thank you, so there is no expression sugar for this ?

Comment: Java 8 lambdas make this lots better, but the static `Maps` methods you're using are what there is.